# instalación de angular

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, npm

Buen dia;

ya instale NodeJs y en símbolo del sistema verifique la versión, como NodeJs por defecto trae npm, verifique tambien la versión del npm, todo OK hasta que voy a intalar Angula CLI version 12.1.4 y me aparece este error:

C:\Users\egonzalez>npm install -g @angular/cli12-1-4
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli12-1-4 - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@angular/cli12-1-4@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\egonzalez\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-01T15_46_00_538Z-debug.log

C:\Users\egonzalez>npm install -g @angular/cli12.1.4
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli12.1.4 - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@angular/cli12.1.4@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\egonzalez\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-01T15_46_09_398Z-debug.log

Me podrian ayudar? pues no entiendo el error.

Comment: `npm install -g @angular/cli@12.1.4`

Comment: Hola, pregunta, si ya esta instalada otra versión? como hago para tener la que requiero, hay que desinstalar y instalar de nuevo angular?

Comment: No es necesario, se reemplaza automáticamente.

Comment: lo reemplace y me aparece esto:     Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands.

Comment: Prueba con `ng version`

Comment: Ya lo busque asi pero me aparece la versión anterior

Comment: Entonces procede con la desinstalación de la versión anterior

Comment: desde simbolo de sistemas lo puedo desinstalar ?

Comment: con estos comandos? $ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
$ npm cache clean
$ npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: ya lo logre, como acepto tu respuesta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para separar las versiones mayores de las menores tienes que utilizar el punto y no el guion, esto es, en lugar de 12-1-4 tienes que escribir 12.1.4. Por otro lado, si estás especificando una versión concreta, como es este caso, no ponga el valor @latest ya que no puedes decirle "instálame esta versión" y decirle "instálame la última" a la vez. Por lo tanto, si quieres instalar la 12.1.4, el comando es

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@12.1.4
```

mientras que si quieres instalar la última, has de usar este comando

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```